# Compare objects in a list to identify those with certain identical key/value pairs and those without

Tags: python, list, object, comparison

Using Python, how can I find objects in a list that share certain key/value pairs, then create two separate lists - one for objects that share those certain key/value pairs, and one for objects that don't?

For example, take the following simple list -

```json
[
    {
        "id": "111",
        "host": "aaa",
        "path": "/b/c/d"
    },
    {
        "id": "222",
        "host": "bbb",
        "path": "/x/y/z"
    },
    {
        "id": "333",
        "host": "aaa",
        "path": "/b/c/d"
    },
    {
        "id": "444",
        "host": "aaa",
        "path": "/b/c/d"
    }
]
```

I'd like to end up with two lists -

- Objects with duplicate `host` and `path`.

  ```json
  [
      {
          "host": "aaa",
          "path": "/b/c/d"
          "ids": [
              "111",
              "333",
              "444",
      }
  ]
  ```
- Objects without duplicate `host` and `path`.

  ```json
  [
      {
          "id": "222",
          "host": "bbb",
          "path": "/x/y/z"
      }
  ]
  ```

My best attempt so far has yielded two lists, but all of the objects in the original list are added to `dups_list`, regardless of whether or not they are actually duplicates.

Please note that I have tried taking a `deepcopy` of `main_list` to use in the second `for` statement, but that yielded the exact same results.

```py
>>> import jsonpickle
>>> main_list = list((dict(Id="111",host="aaa",path="/b/c/d"),dict(Id="222",host="bbb",path="/x/y/z"),dict(Id="333",host="aaa",path="/b/c/d"),dict(Id="444",host="aaa",path="/b/c/d")))
>>> dups_list = list()
>>> non_dups_list = list()
>>> for o in main_list:
...     is_duplicate = False
...     for o2 in main_list:
...         if o2['host'] == o['host'] and o2['path'] == o['path']:
...             is_duplicate = True
...             break
...     if is_duplicate:
...         dups_list.append(o)
...     else:
...         non_dups_list.append(o)
... 
>>> print(jsonpickle.encode(non_dups_list, indent=4))
[]
>>> print(jsonpickle.encode(dups_list, indent=4))
[
    {
        "Id": "111",
        "host": "aaa",
        "path": "/b/c/d"
    },
    {
        "Id": "222",
        "host": "bbb",
        "path": "/x/y/z"
    },
    {
        "Id": "333",
        "host": "aaa",
        "path": "/b/c/d"
    },
    {
        "Id": "444",
        "host": "aaa",
        "path": "/b/c/d"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with *dict/listcomps* :

```
from collections import defaultdict

g = defaultdict(list)

for obj in list_objs:
    g[(obj["host"], obj["path"])].append(obj["id"])

dups = [{"host": k[0], "path": k[1], "ids": v} for k, v in g.items() if len(v) > 1]

uniqs = [obj for obj in list_objs if (obj["host"], obj["path"])
          not in [k for k, v in g.items() if len(v) > 1]]

#12.2 µs ± 316 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

Output :

```
>>> print(dups)
#[{'host': 'aaa', 'path': '/b/c/d', 'ids': ['111', '333', '444']}]

>>> print(uniqs)
#[{'id': '222', 'host': 'bbb', 'path': '/x/y/z'}]
```

Comment: **NB** : `list_objs` is the variable holding the list of *objects/dictionnaries*.

Comment: Perfect, and so much simpler than what I was trying. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using itertools.

```
from itertools import groupby

def get_key(d):
    # Define a custom key function to group by multiple keys
    return d['host'], d['path']

data = [...your data here]

grouped_data = []
for k, g in groupby(sorted(data, key=get_key), key=get_key):
    grouped_data.append({'host': k[0], 'path': k[1], 'ids': [i['id'] for i in list(g)]})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. While this works for the duplicates, it also includes the duplicates, all non-duplicates are also included in the list, rather than being in a separate list. Additionally, other keys are excluded from both results (not included in my examples, will add a note to say it exists), and the non-duplicates are transformed where they should not be (see my example output). But thanks for introducing my to `itertools`.